# How can I catch all the errors that are generated in an Android studio project

Tags: java, android, try-catch

How can I catch all the errors that are generated in an Android studio project using Java without having to put Try Catch blocks in all the statements, this is because I want to log all the errors in a repository.

Thank you very much for any advice you can give me.

Comment: wrap everything inside a huge try-catch?..

Answer (score 1):

Standard java way:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler( (thread, throwable) -> {
        log(throwable.getMessage(), thread.getId());
});
```

which will handle uncaught RuntimeExceptions, and unless otherwise specified it will act for all your application threads.

Just remember the Exceptions are thrown for a reason, and shouldn't be ignored, especially RuntimeExceptions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I will carry out the process in a module to carry out tests. The goal is to review errors and correct them when they occur.